# Compilation error - Variable pointer is uninitialized when used here

Tags: c, pointers, struct, compiler-errors, initialization

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH_OF_A_MACRO    5

struct structS{
    unsigned int scgsToTrace[LENGTH_OF_A_MACRO];
    unsigned int noOfScgsToTrace;
} structS;

int main()
{
  unsigned int scgsToTrace[LENGTH_OF_A_MACRO] = {0};
  unsigned int noOfScgToTrace = 0;

  structS* commonData_p;
  noOfScgToTrace = commonData_p->noOfScgsToTrace; //Q1: Compilation Error

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < noOfScgToTrace; i++) //Q2: noOfScgToTrace garbage value?
  {
    unsigned int scgToTrace = scgsToTrace[i];
    ...............................
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I am trying to assign noOfScgsToTrace from the structS using a pointer variable commonData_p.
But i am getting a compilation error here saying variable "commonData_p" is uninitialized when used here as mentioned near the comment above. Should i initialize it explicitly? and How?
I have two questions here

Question 1: Why is it saying uninitialized here?
Question 2: By initiliazing noOfScgToTrace as 0 does it consider the value as garbage value in the for loop if it doesn't assign properly?

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I think you'll get further if you `typedef`ine: `typedef struct { ... } structS;`. Otherwise the `struct structS` instance named `structS` comes in the way. Also `commonData_p` _is_ uninitialized, so dereferencing it has undefined behavior.

Comment: @evt And where does this pointer structS* commonData_p; point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to name the type of `commonData_p` which is why you get a compilation error. You also forgot to initialize it:

```
struct structS* commonData_p = &structS; // note "struct structS"
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KsoqrY3sW)

Note:

Your `noOfScgToTrace = commonData_p->noOfScgsToTrace;` is fine because the global `structS` is automatically initialized (to zero) but had you moved the declaration into a function, like `main`, it had been uninitialized and reading it would then make your program have undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you suggesting to move the pointer declaration into a main function argument ? 
I tried your suggestion it didn't work. Can you please write in few lines? 
Thanks!

Comment: @revt No, I'm suggesting that you just add `struct` first (because the type is `struct structS*`, not `structS*` because you didn't `typedef`ine it) and that you also assign a value (`&structS`) to it. I added a demo to the answer.

Comment: Ok, got it. That is good input. How come initializing changes if i have typedef struct {} ?

Comment: @revt No, the initialization doesn't change. `typedef`ining only gives you an alias name so you don't take to write `struct structS` every time you want to use that type. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Gj18T5EKn) - Note that I named the type `structS_t` instead of `structS`. Having the same name on variables as types makes everything confusing to read. :-) Also note that I zero initialized `structS` when I moved the declaration into `main`.

Comment: @revt Typo above: It should have been "_... so you don't **have** to write ..._" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a structure `structS` and a pointer to such a type, `commonData_p`. But you have never assigned anything to that pointer - it's unitialized. You need to extend the line

```
 struct structS* commonData_p = &structS;
```

in order to let the compiler know where the point to.

Answer (score 0):

This compilation error

> Compilation error - Variable pointer is uninitialized when used here

means two things.

The first one is that typing the code in your question you made a typo by omitting typedef specifier.. That is instead of

```
struct structS{
    unsigned int scgsToTrace[LENGTH_OF_A_MACRO];
    unsigned int noOfScgsToTrace;
} structS;
```

there must be

```
typedef struct structS{
    unsigned int scgsToTrace[LENGTH_OF_A_MACRO];
    unsigned int noOfScgsToTrace;
} structS;
```

Otherwise the compiler would issue another error.

And the second one is that you declared an uninitialized pointer

```
structS* commonData_p;
noOfScgToTrace = commonData_p->noOfScgsToTrace; //Q1: Compilation Error
```

that has an indeterminate value. So the compiler issues an error that you are trying to access memory (`commonData_p->noOfScgsToTrace`) using an uninitialized pointer.